# How to take the Wikipedia urls collected and put them into a CSV file with the headings of source_url, link_url, link_title?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, wikipedia

So the code used below was used for scraping urls off of wikipedia pages. My goal was to begin on the wikipedia page 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles' and collect 10 unique links to pages from that webpage that are also from wikipedia. From there I wanted to select one link from what I've collected on the first page and scrape that page for another 10 unique links in wikipedia and repeat this process until I have at least 100 unique links from 10 different wiki pages. Then I wanted to put what I've collected in a CSV file where the data collected is put into the headings of source url, link url, and link title.

I'm struggling on how to do this as I am very new to using python. In my code below I've managed to collect data and put it in a CSV file but I don't know how to get the data to be assigned to the three headings of source url, link url, and link title in the CSV file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

def is_valid(url):

    if url:
        if url.startswith('/wiki/'): 
            if not re.compile('/\w+:').search(url):
                return True

    return False


starter_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles'

r = requests.get(starter_url)
print('url:', r.url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'firstHeading'})

print('starting website:', r.url)
print('titled:', title.text)
print()

valid_urls = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    url = link.get('href', '')
    if url not in valid_urls and is_valid(url):
        valid_urls.append(url)


print('\n'.join(valid_urls))

df = pd.DataFrame(valid_urls)

df.to_csv('WebCrawler.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you like to store your data in a list of dicts while iterating over your `ResultSet` and create a `DataFrame` based on this.

You could also select your elements more specific with `css seletors` and use a `set()` to avoid duplicates:

```
for link in set(soup.select('a[href^="/wiki/"]')):
    data.append({
        'source url':starter_url,
        'source title':title,
        'link url':link['href'],
        'link title':link.text
    })
```

**Note** *Was not sure wich link text you like to assign, so I used both just to show how it works, simply skip the one you do not need*

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

starter_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles'

r = requests.get(starter_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'firstHeading'})

data = []

for link in set(soup.select('a[href^="/wiki/"]')):
    data.append({
        'source url':starter_url,
        'source title':title,
        'link url':link['href'],
        'link title':link.text
    })


pd.DataFrame(data)#.to_csv('WebCrawler.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

##### Output

| source url | source title | link url | link title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles | Wikipedia:Most-referenced articles | /wiki/History_of_the_National_Register_of_Historic_Places | History of the National Register of Historic Places |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles | Wikipedia:Most-referenced articles | /wiki/1950_United_States_Census | 1950_United_States_Census |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles | Wikipedia:Most-referenced articles | /wiki/1959 | 1959 |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles | Wikipedia:Most-referenced articles | /wiki/Special:UncategorizedTemplates | Uncategorized templates |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles | Wikipedia:Most-referenced articles | /wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/1790_United_States_Census | 297 links |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles | Wikipedia:Most-referenced articles | /wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/1882 | 720 links |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles | Wikipedia:Most-referenced articles | /wiki/User:Rambot | User:Rambot |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles | Wikipedia:Most-referenced articles | /wiki/1981 | 1981 |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Most-referenced_articles | Wikipedia:Most-referenced articles | /wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/1960_United_States_Census | 5355 links |